# Looking for algorithms based on sorting

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

i am looking for algorithms which use sorting in low-dimensional space like $R$ and how they are generalized for higher-dimensional spaces like $R^2$ where there is no sorting possible. (i.e. numbers you can sort, for vectors you can't have a real order)

Comment: I think this question is too broad. -- Can you perhaps be more precise in what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The magic words are: [k-d tree.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)